# C# Word enlarge cell using paragraphs

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-automation

I would like to enlarge a cell to a certain height by using paragraphs. i have tried working with height, but it always gives me the same height back, no matter how many paragraphs i insert. is there a way to determine the exact size?

```
var cell = table.Cell(1, 1);
var limitHeight = 6f;

while (cell.Height <= limitHeight)
{
    cell.Range.Text += "\r";
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `"\n"` instead? Or even `Environment.NewLine`? Also, `originalCellHeight` will never change here, so you should either use `cell.Height <= limitHeight` or re-assign this value to your variable

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the code, it was a copied out of context. "\n" and Enviroment.Newline have the same effect, I still get the original height back.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not very clear. Are you saying the problem is solved, now? If not, can you confirm that you're trying to set an exact cell height and are having difficulties with that?

Comment: Not solved yet. I am trying to enlarge the cell to a certain limit. I can’t set a fixed value because it will be dynamically generated. The more paragraphs i insert, the larger the cell grows. I can see this while debugging in word live mode. But I can’t get the height/size of this growing cell.

Comment: I don't really understand, you want to make it grow until it reaches a **known** height (i.e. `limitHeight`), but you can't directly set it (`cell.Height = limitHeight;`)?